# Distribution of sum of quadratic gaussian matrices

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two gaussian matrices, $\textbf{Z}_1 \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ and $\textbf{Z}_2 \in \mathbb{C}^{(T-M) \times N}$  where each entry in $\textbf{Z}_1$ and $\textbf{Z}_2$ is i.i.d. as $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$.

I am interested in the distribution of the quadraticsum of the two matrices
\begin{equation}
 \Sigma^{1/2} \textbf{Z}_1  \quad \text{and} \quad \textbf{Z}_2
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. Namely

\begin{equation}
 \textbf{Z}_1^H \Sigma  \textbf{Z}_1 + \textbf{Z}_2^H\textbf{Z}_2 .
\end{equation}

In the scalar case, it is called a generalized chi-square distribution but I have not found anything in the literature for the multivariate case.

Is there a known distribution for this sum?

Comment: Exactly what you are looking for: http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stated by you translates to finding the distribution of sum of two independent Wishart matrices. The covariance matrix corresponding to one of them is a unit matrix, while for the other one, it is arbitrary. The distribution for this sum can be obtained in terms of a hypergeometric function of matrix arguments,
$$P(H)\propto\text{det}^{T-N}H\,e^{-\text{tr}(\Sigma^{-1}H)}\,_1F_1(T-M;T;(\Sigma^{-1}-\mathbb{1}_N)H)\\\propto\text{det}^{T-N}H\,e^{-\text{tr }H}\,_1F_1(M;T;(\mathbb{1}_N-\Sigma^{-1})H).$$
Here 'det' and 'tr' represent determinant and trace, respectively.
 In fact the result can be obtained even when both the covariance matrices are arbitrary. You can find the details here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6638